# Pip3 trying to install in wrong python directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I recently installed Fedora 26, and it came with python3.6 already installed. However, the application I plan on running uses python3.4 instead. I want to continue using python3.4 so I installed it using dnf. So when I type `pip3 -V` to se what version of pip3 I'm using, I get this: `pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)`. How would I make it so that pip3 installs in `pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4)` instead of python3.6?

Here are some things I have tried.
When running this command `python3.4 -m pip`, I get this error: `/usr/bin/python3.4: No module named pip`. When I tried to reinstall pip, it reinstalls pip-3.6. Also, I noticed that I don't have the pip-3.4 package.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download [this](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) script

Open your terminal and execute it using the command

```
[root@server ~]# python3.4 get-pip.py
```

This should install `pip` to your `Python 3.4` installation

Then you can access your `pip` package manager for your `Python 3.4` installation using

```
[root@server ~]# python3.4 -m pip install <module>
```

Output on my computer:

```
 >> ekavala@elx750xhv:~$ python3.4 --version
 > Python 3.4.3
 >> ekavala@elx750xhv:~$ python3.4 -m pip -V
 > pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (python 3.4)
```

Comment: Dont forget to mark is as an answer and updoot if it worked

Comment: I marked it. Also, I have little reputation, so my upvote doesn't count.

Comment: Your imaginary upvote counts. Best of luck with the application!